# What is MS Residual, and how it differs from the common aleatory error?

Tags: regression, least-squares

Hello I have two questions.
I am trying to understand this formulas. But I cant understand how the MS Residual is different from the common aleatory error

[image]

Another thing, I just labeled each value with the with their supposed corresponding formula, it is correct?

Comment: What is "*common aleatory error*"?

Comment: $MS_{residual}$ probably means "Mean Squared Residual" and doesn't refer to any specific error (hence the "approx" in the last line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OLS model assumptions are that $y_i=\beta^\top x_i + \epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_i\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, $\text{MS}_{\text{residual}}:=\frac 1 n \sum_i(y_i-\hat{\beta}^\top x_i)^2$ is (only) an **approximation** of the variance $\sigma^2$ for two reasons

##### 1. $\hat \beta\approx\beta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ (holds in expectation)

The OLS estimator $\hat\beta$ is unbiased as $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat \beta\right]=\beta$ and the expected error converges to 0 in the limit since $\mathbb{E}\left[||\hat\beta-\beta||^2\right]=\frac {\sigma^2d}{n}$

##### 2. $\frac 1 n \sum_i(y_i-\beta^\top x_i)^2=\frac 1 n \sum_i\epsilon_i^2 \approx\sigma^2$ (holds in limit)

By the law of large numbers, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\frac 1 n\sum_i\epsilon_i^2\rightarrow\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon_i^2\right]=\sigma^2$

Search "Statistical guarantees for ordinary least squares" for proofs and such

Comment: Nice answer! It would be great if you could specify a bit better "holds in expectation" and "holds in limit" as well as adding more complete infos about your reference to that paper (I guess it's a paper). Thank you

Comment: These are very standard undergrad level results, as such I do not think you need/would be able to find a paper, but maybe some free course material. You could easily prove them yourself or find them online. But alright, I will include them here directly.

Comment: Someone asking that kind of question likely is not familiar with terms like "holds in expectation". Also, the way you reported *Statistical guarantees for ordinary least square* it sounded like the title of an article or book. I think it just needed to be easier to follow for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for your time !